# strange behaviour with redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am creating a social media app, the user can put a post and users can like or comment that post, all users posts will be shown in the home page, and a certain user's posts will be shown in his profile page

**My problem**, liking functionality doesn't work properly:

The problem exists in my reducer, this is my code:

```
 case LIKE_POST:
    case UNLIKE_POST:
        const allPosts= state.posts.map(post=> {
            if (post.postId === action.payload.postId) {
                return {
                    ...post,
                    likeCount: action.payload.likeCount
                }
            }
            return post;
        });

        const userPosts= state.userData.posts.map(post=> {
            if (post.postId === action.payload.postId) {
                return {
                    ...post, 
                    likeCount: action.payload.likeCount
                }
            }
            return post;
        })

        return {
            ...state,
            posts: allPosts,
            userData: {
                ...state.userData,
                posts: userPosts
            }
        }
```

it seems that liking functionality doesn't work in both pages, when i remove that part in the reducer:

```
        const userPosts= state.userData.posts.map(post=> {
            if (post.postId === action.payload.postId) {
                return {
                    ...post, 
                    likeCount: action.payload.likeCount
                }
            }
            return post;
        })
```

Liking functionality works well in home page, and when remove that part

```
 const allPosts= state.posts.map(post=> {
            if (post.postId === action.payload.postId) {
                return {
                    ...post,
                    likeCount: action.payload.likeCount
                }
            }
            return post;
        });
```

Liking works well in user page.

I can't make them both works together, i can't post more code because it is complex, but at least why removing one part make the other works well??

Comment: is there a typo in the code pasted in question or is it in your actual code as well?  
`posts:posts` should be  `posts: allPosts` in return

Comment: If you are mistakenly marking `posts` as null, and then you might be accessing them somewhere in other part of code, like posts.length, which would produce error and make the other one stop to work as well.

Comment: @AtifSaddique thank you i fixed that, you can see the update

Comment: Is there a strict criteria to distinguish *'..liking functionality doesn't work properly'* from *'..Liking functionality works well'*? What's the problem exactly? To demonstrate your problem, you don't necessarily need to copy paste all the code into your question, but you may post the link to the live snippet on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or whatever you feel comfortable with.

Comment: Hi, I would advise to write the reducer a bit clearly so that the probability of having bugs could be reduced.    
1. Try to keep the posts in state only once, don't duplicate in `userData` inside state.    
2. Try to handle the both like and unlike cases separately without passing the likeCount.

Comment: case LIKE_POST: {
    const posts = state.posts.map(post => (
        post.postId === action.payload.postId ? {
            ...post,
            likeCount: ++post.likeCount
        } : post
    
    ));
    return {
        ...state,
        posts: posts
    }
}

case UNLIKE_POST: {
    const posts = state.posts.map(post => (
        post.postId === action.payload.postId ? {
            ...post,
            likeCount: --post.likeCount
        } : post
    
    ));
    return {
        ...state,
        posts: posts
    }
}